# Python Anywhere - No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._stochastic_gradient'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, pythonanywhere

I want to use the **pickle** module and serialize the model learned on my computer:

```
pickle.dump(clf, open(os.path.join(dest, 'classifier.pkl'), 'wb'), protocol=4)
```

When I open it **on my computer as well**, everything works fine:

```
clf = pickle.load(open(os.path.join('pkl_objects', 'classifier.pkl'), 'rb'))
```

Unfortunately when I do the same on **pythonanywhere.com I get the error**:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model._stochastic_gradient'
```

I have the following versions scikit-learn:

- on my computer: 0.23.2
- pythonanywhere.com is 0.21.3

How to standardize it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `requirement.txt` file where you define all the necessary dependencies with versions. Or you can make a virtual environment like they have in the [docs](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/). Or you can try running `pip install scikit-learn --upgrade`.

Comment: Thanx. I upgraded scikit-learn on pythonanywhere to the same version like on my computer in bash console:      pip3.8 install --user sklearn --upgrade scikit-learn==0.23.2

Answer (score 0):

These code also helped me:

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
model_SGDRegressor=SGDRegressor()

Comment: This answer might benefit from some improvement. More explanatory information would be useful.